# Chrome content_scripts not detecting angular navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to create a chrome extension for a particular Angular App using content_scripts.

The app has multiple routes, but I want the content script to run on a particular route.

So I have defined it in the `matches` array in manifest: `https://example.com/mypage1/*`

It works fine if I load the app directly on that page. However, if I navigate to the page from another page, the content script does not detect that.

I believe this navigation is happening in Angular, and as its not href navigation, the content_script doesn't detect this navigation.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try listening to location change, maybe that will work `window.addEventListener('locationchange', ...`

Comment: It's because the page is using fake navigation via history.pushState. You can detect it via  `navigation.onnavigate` event.